# Resize PictureBox with its related controls

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

I have a PictureBox where I put some other controls (smaller PictureBoxes, labels..).

```
PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
pictureBox.Size = new Size(Width, Height);
pictureBox.Location = new Point(0, 0); 
pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

// add child controls

PictureBox iconPictureBox = new PictureBox();
iconPictureBox.Location = new Point(icon.x, icon.y);
iconPictureBox.Size = new Size(icon.width, icon.height);
iconPictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
iconPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(resourcesPath);
iconPictureBox.Click += IconPictureBox_Click;
pictureBox.Controls.Add(iconPictureBox);
```

When I tried to attach the main picture box "pictureBox" to the MainForm window using Controls.Add, after setting the new size and position of the picture box, it is drawn in the correct place with correct size but the contents are not stretched i.e. their positions are not changed.

Is there a method to make the related controls stretched within the main pictureBox?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to set their `Anchor` or `Dock` properties correctly.

Comment: Dock is useless here. Anchor will do a little but more likely you need to write the code yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used the scale method to resize the container, and added the stretch property to all child controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scale method of the forms container (PictureBox or Panel) can be used to resize it, all child forms should have the SizeMode to stretch so that they will follow the scaling.